# IdentityServer 4 Restfull Login/Logout

Tags: identityserver4

Been looking into the identity server 4 solution to compliment my ASP CORE api.
Using a SPA page on front end, does IdentityServer4 have the capability to manage restfull calls for login/logout/other?

Currently my solution works perfectly to redirect to and from the IdentityServer4 solution, but wondering if i can improve on UX by avoiding the redirects that occur on login/logout?

I've heard of PopUp and iFrame capability, but from research that opens up other risks.

(not sure if this question is for stackoverflow or software engineering stack, happy to move it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do this by using the resource owner password grant type, where you could provide your own login screen and pass the information to IdentityServer.

In IdentityServer you would implement the [IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/resource_owner.html#refresourceownerpasswordvalidator) interface to validate the users.

In your Startup.ConfigureServices add the following.

```
Services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
```

Here is a sample ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator class.

```
public class ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator : IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator
    {
        private IUserManager _myUserManager { get; set; }

        public ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator(IUserManager userManager)
        {
            _myUserManager = userManager;
        }        

        public async Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
        {            
            var user = await _myUserManager.Find(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user != null)
            {
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(
                        subject: user.USER_ID,
                        authenticationMethod: "custom",
                        claims: await _myUserManager.GetClaimsAsync(user));
            }
            else
            {                 
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(
                        TokenRequestErrors.InvalidRequest, 
                        errorDescription: "UserName or Password Incorrect.");
            }             
        }
    }
```

The `IUserManager` implements the logic to check the database to validate the user.

Then the SPA client would use the `GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword`. Here is an [example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Clients/src/ConsoleResourceOwnerFlow) you could start with.

**DISCLAIMER**
This is not the recommended flow to use.

Comment: I know its been a while, but out of curiosity why not just implement a a restful action? Reason i ask is i am trying to figure out how to create restful login and registration so that my current mobile apps can leverage it.

Comment: @Aeseir if the user has to enter a username and password, you do not want that 'page' to be part of the mobile app because it can be hacked and stolen. Mobile devices are high risk for malicious code since we can not guarantee their security.

Comment: thanks for that. I am trying to understand how does firebase and the alike then do their restful login. For e.g. ionic mobile apps primarily use restful login, as integration with inbrowserapp is extremely painful. There must be a level of assumed responsiblity on client side.

Comment: @Aeseir you would use Firebase SDK authentication

Comment: I have used, they use a restful method there. Wouldn't that be a security issue?

Comment: Yes after looking at that you don’t want to do that! Your app should redirect to the IdentityServer4 where tat is the only place user credentials are used.

Comment: Thanks. Obviously google has gone down the restful path with firebase. If I decided to implement something similar can the risk of security breach be mitigated by additional controls (blue sky thinking here)?

Comment: They are using the OAuth 2.0 password credential flow which is not recommended for most situations