# IdentityServer 4, Create Panel to CRUD Clients

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, identityserver4

Currently I Have configured Identityserver4 as separated project + My WebAPI and store in DB Credentials in IdentityServer.

Now i have problem how to make CRUD(In my frontend API) to IdentityServer(I want from my API add Clients to IdentityServer)

How to make property?

Comment: Are you looking to add a GUI to perform admin CRUD functions on the clients defined for use by IdentityServer4?

Comment: @aaronR - Yes, i want write in my APi methods to CRUD clients

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [`IdentityServer4.EntityFramework`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework) and [`IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage), you have access to [`IConfigurationDbContext`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage/blob/master/src/Interfaces/IConfigurationDbContext.cs#L16) (once you've added the required services in `ConfigureServices` using e.g. [`AddConfigurationStore`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/blob/master/src/IdentityServerEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.cs#L30)). Because this is registered as part of the Dependency Injection system, you can take a dependency on it in one of your controllers. e.g.:

```
public class ClientsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfigurationDbContext _configurationDbContext;

    public ClientsController(IConfigurationDbContext configurationDbContext)
    {
        _configurationDbContext = configurationDbContext;
    }

    // ...
}
```

`IConfigurationDbContext` is an abstraction of a standard `DbContext`, with the following `DbSet<T>` properties:

- `Clients`
- `IdentityResources`
- `ApiResources`

It also includes both `SaveChanges` and `SaveChangesAsync` - Everything one might expect from a `DbContext`. Because of all of this, you can CRUD each of these entities just like any other Entity Framework Core driven database.

One final thing to note is that there are both [`Models`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Storage/tree/master/src/Models) (in `IdentityServer4.Storage`) and [`Entities`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage/tree/master/src/Entities) (in `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage`). There are also a few extension methods for mapping between these (e.g. [`ClientMappers.ToEntity`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage/blob/master/src/Mappers/ClientMappers.cs#L37)).

Given all of this, you can create a `Model` inside of your controller (or perhaps somewhere much better encapsulated than directly there). Here's a basic example for creating a new `Client`:

```
var clientModel = new Client
{
    ClientId = "",
    ClientName = "",
    // ...
};

_configurationDbContext.Clients.Add(clientModel.ToEntity());

await _configurationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The `Client` class here comes from `IdentityServer4.Models` and is then converted to an `Entity` using a `ToEntity` extension method I hinted at above. Working with a `Model` and converting to an `Entity` is simpler than trying to manipulate an `Entity` directly - If you're interested, you can see the [mapping](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage/blob/master/src/Mappers/ClientMapperProfile.cs#L22) that takes place here.

This works in the same way for `ApiResources`, `IdentityResources`, etc. Use the source code links I've provided if you want to find out more about those specifically, but the information I've provided here should have you covered.

In order to use `IdentityServer4` and `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework` in your API project, you can just add the two references to your API project. After that, you can configure the DI in the same way (using `AddIdentityServer` in `ConfigureServices`), but you don't need to add the middleware (using `UseIdentityServer` in `Configure`). You can even just use `AddIdentityServer().AddConfigurationStore(...)` to set up the relevant services, as you don't need a signing key, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by bootstrapping the ID4 Quickstart (tutorial located here):
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html

Other option is to use their quickstart seeds located here to speed this up:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples

Now if you want to implement restfull login there are constraints around it (i wanted to find out as well) check out this question:
[IdentityServer 4 Restfull Login/Logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880662/identityserver-4-restfull-login-logout)

Comment: It isn't my problem. LogIn and Log Out to implement is quite easy. I want a dynamicly Add,Create,Remove users from Identityserver. And i searching how do this?