# Identityserver4 authentication - login and registration handled in client angular application without redirection

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Is it possible to handle login and registration in identityserver4 using asp.net identity and to **not** be redirected to server page from client javascript(angular5) app?

I am developing app that consists of multiple API's. I want to have all of them protected but one (frontoffice) should be accessible both from angular by lets say individual user accounts and by other API's. While I'm able to do API to API authorization (from tutorials) i'm struggling a bit with angular one. I saw identityserver4 doc's page but theres no mention if its possible to implement this concrete scenario.

Do i have to live with this redirection or is it possible to make a direct call from angular or something? Maybe there is some different library that i can use except identityserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So two things you are asking from what i gather:

1. Can you have restfull login/logout
2. Can login/logout be triggered from Angular

My feedback

1. Yes you can, but not recommended. I personally asked this question while back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880662/identityserver-4-restfull-login-logout). There are security risks involved with this approach but you can do it if you happy to take the risk
2. Yes you can trigger it from angular, either construct your own if you have implemented custom restfull login/logout or use a existing package to leverage the standard redirect process (personally i use this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-auth-oidc-client) to integrate my angular app with my identity server.